# Android webservice client access to xml files

Tags: android, xml, web-services, rest

I have created an android webservicce client. When i call the webservice, certain operations happen on my webservice which produces various xml files. How can i access those xml files in my android code?

Comment: If you use a REST, you don't get a whole File.
You should get a String in the HTTP-Response (your xml-content). You have to parse this in your App.

Comment: No my webservice is not returning xml file. It is just generating xml files. I need to send those files to my Android Client.

Comment: Or how to just return the xml file and recieve it in my android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://simple.sourceforge.net/  Saxparser  or xml pull parser

Comment: What should i look for in that? Sorry i am a beginner.

Comment: In your question, it says when u call the webservice it produces some xml files? or xml response

Answer (score 0):

First create a Method on you REST to return a download-url to the XML-Files on the server. The ServerSide implementation depends on the REST you are using (Java, C#, ....)

Then use this URL to download the Files onto your Android device.
Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog).